# MongoDB multi-document transaction: MongoQueryException (Transaction is not active)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-transactions, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm testing simple use case for multi-document transactions.

But the context is more specific.

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB with MongoDB API 4.0.

This is the sample code (I want to make this work using MongoRepository interface):

```
@Transactional(value = "mongoTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public void saveData() {

    repoType1.insert(MyType1.builder().id("1").build());

    repoType1.insert(MyType1.builder().id("2").build());

    // different document
    repoType2.insert(MyType2.builder().id("1234567").build());

    if (true) {
      throw new RuntimeException("should rollback everything!");
    }

    repoType1.insert(
        MyType1.builder().id("3").build());
}


@Bean
MongoTransactionManager mongoTransactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}

@Repository
@Transactional(value = "mongoTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public interface MyType1Repository
    extends MongoRepository<MyType1, String> {
}

@Repository
@Transactional(value = "mongoTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public interface MyType2Repository
    extends MongoRepository<MyType1, String> {
}
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2
> (BadValue): 'Error=2, Details='Response status code does not indicate
> success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 1101; ActivityId:
> 6645fc9e-2c26-4c4a-841d-4a1236b1b7b6; Reason: (Message:
> {"Errors":["Transaction is not active"]} ActivityId:
> 6645fc9e-2c26-4c4a-841d-4a1236b1b7b6, Request URI:
> /apps/42c66b5d-4a29-4cc3-8eec-6f40b63129b6/services/102e98fc-69a2-45fe-8b26-4a5ed4c052af/partitions/941605a6-2524-48c2-9937-b518ca9b477e/replicas/133108113341839198p/,
> RequestStats:
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceData.ClientSideRequestStatisticsTraceDatum,
> SDK: Windows/10.0.19041 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0);' on server
> cosmos-core-midware-test-001-westeurope.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255.
> The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Error=2, Details='Response
> status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus:
> 1101; ActivityId: 6645fc9e-2c26-4c4a-841d-4a1236b1b7b6; Reason:
> (Message: {"Errors":["Transaction is not active"]}\r\nActivityId:
> 6645fc9e-2c26-4c4a-841d-4a1236b1b7b6, Request URI:
> /apps/42c66b5d-4a29-4cc3-8eec-6f40b63129b6/services/102e98fc-69a2-45fe-8b26-4a5ed4c052af/partitions/941605a6-2524-48c2-9937-b518ca9b477e/replicas/133108113341839198p/,
> RequestStats:
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceData.ClientSideRequestStatisticsTraceDatum,
> SDK: Windows/10.0.19041 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0);", "code": 2,
> "codeName": "BadValue"}

I tested the transaction and it works when only calling insert on a single document.

Could this be MongoDB API version issue? (Would upgrading to 4.2. make any difference)

From Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API 4.2. documentation:

[image]

To me this is very poorly documented I'm aware that sharded collections don't support multi-document transactions, but what about db instances that don't required sharding...

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with whether the documents themselves are on different shards. It applies to whether the collection itself was created as fixed or sharded.

There is an article in the Cosmos DB for MongoDB that talks about this specifically, [Use Multi-document transactions in Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/use-multi-document-transactions)

If creating using Azure portal it is the highlighted item you need to select here.

[image]

Comment: from the link you posted "Multi-document transactions are not supported across collections or in sharded collections in 4.0. " - what would "across collections" mean? Does that mean that you can only have transaction over one collection (but multiple-documents are allowed)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Multiple documents within one "fixed" collection.